# Solicitação de "atualização" de resposta

Tags: novo-recurso

Em diversos casos, acabamos nos deparando com **perguntas antigas, tais como suas respostas**.

Para não "duplicar", seria legal um botão "**Solitar atualização**", assim a pessoa que respondeu, recebe uma mensagem da solicitação, e atualiza, ou não, a resposta.

Assim seria útil para não gerar duplicidade.

Até mesmo quem respondeu poderá ter adquirido novos conhecimentos que seriam úteis para a resposta, adicionar novos conceitos, ou seja, **conteúdo útil**.

Comment: Não fui eu quem negativou, mas simplesmente não entendi nada. Se a resposta precisa ser editada é porque a pergunta foi alterada e se a pergunta foi alterada de maneira tão drástica a ponto da resposta ter que ser refeita ou ter que adicionar detalhes na maioria dos casos então foi a edição na **pergunta** que foi precipitada e o correto seria o AP (autor da pergunta) abrir uma nova pergunta ao invés de descaracterizar a pergunta antiga.

Comment: Não entendi, se a resposta já existe, porque precisaria ser atualizada ? Por exemplo essa pergunta: [**Por que não devemos usar funções do tipo mysql_\*?**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/297358) o que precisaria ser editado na melhor resposta para evitar  duplicidade? No site a um campo de pesquisa, diminuiria se o povo utilizasse o mesmo ou até mesmo uma pesquisa no *Google*.

Comment: A o povo adora downvote sem justificativa aqui ! Rs É verdade, tem sentido o que disse, concordo. Mas no meu caso, que não sei se mudou drasticamente ou não, eu então arriscaria abrir uma pergunta nova, correndo o risco de alguém marcar como duplicada mas as vezes também se confundir quanto a ao estar atualizado ou não... Ou até sugerir uma recompensa (como sugerido pelo Maniero)... ou uma sinalização... Sei lá... acho que você me confundiu mais ainda ! Hahaha

Comment: @NoobSaibot Tipo uma questão sobre "tecnologias", que as vezes surgiu uma nova ou até mesmo uma atualização que deixou a resposta defesada. Mas aí poderia a pergunta não bater com a resposta, como o Guilherme disse. Mas como saberei (pensando no SO) se está ou não defasada !? Mas estão certo... acho que iria atrapalhar. :\

Comment: Eu acho que o recurso de oferecer a recompensa é uma opção suficientemente adequada para esse caso mesmo. Primeiro que você pode adicionar um texto ao oferecer a recompensa, onde você pode justificar qual a sua expectativa sobre a pergunta (ou as respostas no caso). Segundo que uma funcionalidade dessas transmite a idéia de uma responsabilidade exagerada para o autor da resposta, pois é como se nós estivéssemos atribuindo a ele o dever de dar uma nova resposta, ou atualizá-la, quando esse papel é da comunidade como um todo.

Comment: Cara não sei se era exatamente isso que vc pretendia com a pergunta, mas o que eu vejo é pergunta antiga, com resposta antiga que já não é mais a realidade, ou então existe um jeito novo de resolver. Nesses casos eu prefiro responder, pois é uma nova informação, que em alguns casos mesmo o Edit da resposta anterior não resolveria...

Comment: @hugocsl é, concordo com vocês. É que eu fui no conceito de uma pergunta que seria mais "teórica" do que lógica. Olha aqui: [Link](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/85591) Mas mesmo assim, acho que pergunta antiga realmente se for atualizada, sai fora do contexto. O único problema, seria eu fazer uma pergunta quase igual, e ela ser tratada como "duplicada" entende.

Comment: Te entendo RBZ, nesse caso eu citaria a pergunta antiga e falaria que agora a situação é outra que vc precisa de uma resposta que aborde a questão do ponte de vista X e não do ponto Y como na outra... É só uma opiniçao minha de qq forma, pode ser que a comunidade não entenda assim, então não deixa de ser um "risco"

Comment: Acredito que, pra esses tipos de caso, existe a opção ao oferecer uma recompensa: _"**As respostas atuais estão desatualizadas.** As respostas estão desatualizadas e precisam ser revisadas, devido às recentes alterações."_

Comment: @GuilhermeCostamilam Sim, foi o que o Maniero disse no link que passei. No final, é isso. Estou ruim ideias para novas ferramentas ! hahaha